# When should apply factory method in the aggregate root?

Tags: domain-driven-design, aggregate, factory

Domain-driven design suggest that we should create an aggregate root by using a factory to hide the complexity. We can use the following ways to create the aggregate root:

1. Static factory method in a factory class
2. Aggregate root that has a factory method

On What basis do we make a selection between (1) and (2)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider having a factory method on the on the AR when the resulting code aligns better with your ubiquitous language and when the AR has some knowledge that will simplify the creation process.

For instance, if in your domain you can add tasks to a project and tasks are modeled as ARs then `Task task = project.addTask(taskId, taskName);` is more expressive and simple than `Task task = new Task(taskId, taskName, projectId);`.

Answer (score 3):

Factories are not exactly specific to DDD. You can find the Factory pattern in GoF, for example.

Usually, you make your choice based on the following:

- If your factory returns different types, depending on the arguments, it should be placed in a class
- If your factory always returns an instance of one class, it should be made as a static method inside this class

When it comes to DDD, you normally would have factory methods on your aggregate roots anyway, to encapsulate the complex creation logic, if you have such logic of course. Factories are named according your Ubiquitous Language and ensure that only consistent aggregates can be created.

Answer (score 1):

Your first suggestion

> Static factory method in a factory class

is something you should generally avoid. Public static methods are a code smell if they have service character (which factories do). **It's better to create a non-static class, inject it wherever it is used and call the instance method on it. Create an interface if necessary. This approach improves testability and makes dependencies between classes explicit.**

If you follow this advice, your question becomes a question of **factory method pattern** vs **abstract factory pattern**.

### Factory Method

Use factory methods when there are multiple ways to construct an object of a certain class. Factory methods are preferable to direct constructor calls in this case because you can give them a descriptive name. If you use them, it usually makes sense to make the constructor private, so that clients realize that they should not call the constructor, but call the appropriate factory method.

Factory methods just wrap the constructor. As a consequence, they cannot really simplify the construction of an object (apart from giving it a name).

### Abstract Factory

If constructing an object is non-trivial, the pattern of choice is the *abstract factory pattern*. Note that you are not required to have multiple classes to be able to use an abstract factory as suggested by Alexey Zimarev. An abstract factory makes perfect sense with just one type of object that is being created.

Abstract factories are a special kind of a service, namely a service that creates objects. As such, they can have dependencies, which they can provide to the created objects for example.

Example: Let's say you want to create an object that needs a string value and a dependency to `ISomeService`. Here, an abstract factory can help by providing `ISomeService`. The interface of the factory would then look like this:

```
interface IFooFactory {
    IBar CreateBar(string value);
}
```

This factory simplifies creation of an `IBar` for clients, because they don't have to provide the `ISomeService` themselves.

### In the context of DDD Aggregates

Aggregates often contain references to domain services. **As such, instantiation of aggregates is often non-trivial, so the abstract factory pattern is a good fit here.**

Comment: I have not state any *requirement* to have multiple classes in order to use abstract factory. Concerning abstract factory being a good fit for aggregates, the answer would always be "it depends". If you have references to domain services for your factory, I would do it in a separate factory and service class, otherwise in a method. But I support your answer also because the blue book suggests the same, being, by the way, in conflict with the red book.

Comment: @theDmi you don't need **the** Abstract Factory pattern (i.e. where the type of created object is polymorphic) to do this. **A** Factory (in the DDD sense of the word) abstraction is enough. Domain entities rarely need to be abstract classes or interfaces.

Comment: @guillaume31 True, but the fact that there is a *GoF Factory Method* and *GoF Abstract Factory* pattern, but no "ordinary" factory pattern, it often helps people to distinguish between just the two and just use a simplified, non-polymorphic version of the abstract factory pattern. But you are right of course.

Comment: @theDmi I think there is indeed one "ordinary" Factory pattern in the original blue book

Comment: Yes there is, but not in the GoF book. My goal was to reduce the problem to the basic GoF patterns, but maybe it is misleading :-)

Comment: Oh, I get you now. But it's still unfair IMO to limit the options to just Factory Method vs Abstract Factory. Especially seeing as Abstract Factory is one of the most overused, misused, misunderstood and misimplemented patterns ever.

Comment: The **blue book** is talking about having Factory method for objects and Factory or Service to create aggregates. The distinction is made like this: "A FACTORY is very tightly coupled to its product, so a FACTORY should be attached only to an object that has a close natural relationship with the product. Where there is something we want to hide - either the concrete implementation or the sheer complexity of construction - yet there doesn't seem to be a natural host, we must create a dedicated FACTORY object or SERVICE".

Answer (score 1):

They are basically the same. Option 1. might help you avoid having a bloated entity class. Option 2. is better if the creation reads more naturally when prefixing by the name of the entity, as in

```
LoyaltyCard.ForCustomer(...)
SavedSearch.WithCriteria(...)
```